# Button scrolling down screen after click stops, after another click starts again

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, scroll

I've got a little problem.
Here's my fiddle:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/ekpgbxrk/][1]
```

My question is: what's wrong with my code? Point is that I want to scroll site down after clicking button and after another click I want to stop, then to proceed.
I used:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html
Please help!

Comment: The request to include code when posting a link to fiddle is there for a reason. Comply with it!

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button onclick function is wrong. Change it to whatever function you'd want to call in your JS code.

Also change your JSFiddle's JS setting "Load Type" to "No wrap in - <head>"

Here is updated logic for your code.

```
var scrolling = false;
var scrollDelay;

function scrollClick() {
    if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    startScroll();
  } else {
    scrolling = false;
    stopScroll();
  }
}

function startScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
  scrolldelay = setTimeout('startScroll()', 125); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}

function stopScroll() {
  clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ekpgbxrk/5/

Comment: Thanks! :) I really appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is completely wrong.

I have rewrote the logic.

For your reference:

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ekpgbxrk/1/
```